# Ruby on Rails production logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

Ruby on Rails 3.2

My environment/production.rb has `config.log_level = :debug` set.

When I console cmd `tail -f log/production.log` it shows this:

```
root@name:/opt/RoR/name# tail -f log/production.log
Compiled jquery.ticker.js  (0ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled jquery.nivo.slider.js  (0ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled bootstrap.min.js  (0ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled jquery-tablesorter/jquery.metadata.js  (0ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled jquery-tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js  (0ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled jquery-tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js  (0ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled jquery-tablesorter.js  (10ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled application.js  (74ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled custom.css  (869ms)  (pid 19976)
Compiled application.css  (872ms)  (pid 19976)
```

It never shows any requests or anything else. How do you view the logs? Thank you

**EDIT**
Shouldn't Passenger be doing something here? In my nginx.conf I have "passenger_enabled on;"

Comment: Are you sure that's the right log file? Is it writable by the user your application runs as? What happens if you spin up `rails console`?

Comment: Just a sanity check, are you running the rails application in production mode?

Comment: @Slicedpan Yes the application is being run in production mode. The development mode log is fine.

Comment: @tadman The production rails console works fine. Also, if I do 'tail -f log/development.log' it works fine.

Comment: So you're seeing entries in `log/development.log`? What environment are you running this in? Sounds like development.

Comment: @tadman When development mode is running the log/development.log works. When production mode is running the log/production.log shows what is shown in my question. The production mode is running, I know for a fact, the DB is different in prodution and Im not using port 3000. What do you mean "What environment are you running this in?" The tail -f log/foo.log is run without any environment. Its tailing the log file.

Comment: What happens if you put `Rails.env` somewhere on your view to show what environment the application is executing in? Generally on a development machine you don't have a parallel production environment. For that it's best to set up a small virtual machine and configure it 100% in production mode. [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) is an easy way to do this. Does production mode work on your production machine? Just trying to eliminate variables here, like if it's specific to your installation or system config.

Comment: A couple of things to check: a) If you've been tailing the log BEFORE you deploy the app, you might be looking at an old log. b) Did you restart your app after changing config.log_level? c) Are you sure you're tailing the log on the correct server?

Comment: @tadman So I placed the Rails.env and it shows production when in production and development when in development.

Comment: @H-man I did not look at the log before but I did restart the app several times. There are only 3 log files in the same folder. The development, production, and test. Where does the app specify the log file being used?

Comment: I have had this issue and noticed that Rails 3.2+, if my memory is right, uses buffered logging, which delays flushing. Keep watching for a little and you should see something =) Alternatively, you can add this to `config/environments/production.rb` `config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log",Rails.env + ".log"),3, 5 * 1024 * 1024))`

Comment: @Abdo Do you know how long it should take?

Comment: @Abdo This is the problem I think, I tried the different logger you gave. I get this error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/RoR/dist_portal/log/production.log (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: Another possibility is Passenger not working correctly.

Comment: do `chmod 777 /opt/RoR/dist_portal/log/production.log` and see if this works =)

Comment: @Abdo That was it. I tried find log/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; first but didn't work. Please post your comment as an answer

Comment: @DDDD done =) Let me know if there's anything missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments above, I have had this issue and noticed that Rails 3.2+, if my memory is right, uses buffered logging, which delays flushing.

Keep watching for a little and you should see something. Alternatively, you can add the code below to `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(
       Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log",Rails.env + ".log"),3, 5 * 1024 * 1024)
)
```

Also, as @DDDD mentioned in the comment below, you might want to make sure that rails has the right permissions to write to the logger. If you are getting a permissions error, you want to try the following:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/log/production.log
```

If this is the case, you want to fix that (change ownership or group of directory?) because when the logging code above splits the logs into multiple files, the problem might recur.

Comment: Added more info... You might want to take a look at the recent edit =)